# JMeter - scripting multi step scenario and only few users to reach the last transaction

Tags: jmeter

I have to prepare a script in JMeter and design a scenario with 100 user load where we have 5 steps:

- Launch
- login
- search item
- add to cart
- checkout

100 users should only do launch action, only 80 users to login, only 50 users to search for Item, only 30 users to add to cart and finally only 10 users to check out.

Comment: Will do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) as a parent for each of the Samplers and use  `Execution Style` as `Total Executions` and put the number of users you wany in `Throughput` field

> Execution Style
>   Whether the controller will run in percent executions or total executions mode.
>
> Throughput
>    For total execution mode, the number indicates the total number of times the controller will execute.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) where you can set either percentage of executions or total executions number. The ratio will be applied to all Throughput Controller's children.
2. [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-weighted-switch-controller-the-ultimate-guide/) where you can set the "weight" of child element(s) which guarantees:

   - that the element(s) will be executed according to the weight defined, or at least once
   - the execution order will be the same (unless you turn on random execution)

Weighted Switch Controller can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/#JMeter-Plugins-Manager)